# AJAX POST Complex JSON to MVC4 Controller

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4, data-binding

I have a complex JSON object that I'd like to pass to a MVC4 Controller route.

```
{
"name": "Test",
"description": "Description",
"questions": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "1",
        "text": "123",
        "answers": [
            {
                "answer": "123",
                "prerequisite": 0
            },
            {
                "answer": "123",
                "prerequisite": 0
            }
        ],
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "type": "2",
                "text": "234",
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "answer": "234",
                        "prerequisite": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "answer": "234",
                        "prerequisite": 0
                    }
                ],
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have these ViewModels defined:

```
public class FormDataTransformContainer
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public QuestionDataTransformContainer[] questions;
}

public class QuestionDataTransformContainer {
    public int type { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public AnswerDataTransformContainer[] answers { get; set; }
    public QuestionDataTransformContainer[] children { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerDataTransformContainer {
    public string answer { get; set; }
    public int prerequisite { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the route I'm hitting:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormDataTransformContainer formData)
    {
```

Currently, the name and description property on FormDataTransformContainer are set, but the questions array is null.  I hoped that the Data Binding would figure it out, but I assume the tree nature of the data structure is a little complex for it.  If I'm correct what is the best solution to this?

Comment: Parse it using a library like [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I was hoping there was some DataBinding magic I was missing out on, but JSON.NET provides the deserialization I need.

Comment: What result are you seeing? I assume your controller method is like `public ActionResult JsonSubmitted(FormDataTransformContainer data)` and if you were to look at `data` in this case, is it null, partially populated, an exception raised before model binder has even finished...?

Comment: Updated the question with a snippet of the route, and what results I'm experiencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`questions` should be a property, not a field. I'd also change from arrays to `IList<>` (assuming your serialization library handles that well), because that's probably closer to what it should be, and lets you use a more generic interface instead of a specific implementation.

```
public class FormDataTransformContainer
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string description { get; set; }
  public IList<QuestionDataTransformContainer> questions { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionDataTransformContainer {
  public int type { get; set; }
  public string text { get; set; }
  public IList<AnswerDataTransformContainer> answers { get; set; }
  public IList<QuestionDataTransformContainer> children { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerDataTransformContainer {
  public string answer { get; set; }
  public int prerequisite { get; set; }
}
```

I've tested this structure with Json.net (MVC4's default, I believe), and it works.

Comment: Making questions a property fixed it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @robert-harvey said, you should utilize libraries like [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) that are already available to do the heavy lifting for you.

Pulled from the JSON.NET API docs:
If you create a `string json` that holds your json, you can read from it with `new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json))`

Answer (score 0):

I a similar problem, solved with the following code:

```
public class ExtendedController : Controller
{
    public T TryCreateModelFromJson<T>(string requestFormKey)
    {
        if (!this.Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains(requestFormKey))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Request form doesn't contain provided key.");
        }

        return
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(
                this.Request.Form[requestFormKey]);
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("EditAjax")]
    public ActionResult EditAjaxPOST()
    {
        try
        {
            var viewModel =
                this.TryCreateModelFromJson<MyModel>(
                    "viewModel");

            this.EditFromModel(viewModel);

            return
                this.JsonResponse(
                    this.T("Model updated successfuly."),
                    true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Logger.Error(ex, "Error while updating model.");

            return this.JsonResponse(this.T("Error"), false);
        }
    }
```

Called from JS:

```
function saveViewModel() {
    $.post(
        '@Url.Action("EditAjax")',
        {
            __RequestVerificationToken: '@Html.AntiForgeryTokenValueOrchard()',
            viewModel: ko.mapping.toJSON(viewModel)
        },
        function (data) {
             // response
        });
}
```

Used additional library for deserializing/serializing JSON: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json